# SQL filter columns for which value in other column is changing

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

If I have a table like this:

```
cbi_key aaa_key
 1        25
 1        25
 1        38
 1        38
 2        40
 2        40
 2        40
```

How do I filter `cbi_key` values for which `aaa_key` is changing, ie here only `cbi_key = 1`?

Expected output:

```
cbi_key
 1
```

Comment: Do you mean you want cbi_key having at least 2 different cbi_key values? Use GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output based on that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could aggregate by `cbi_key` and filter on groups that contain at least two distinct values of `aa_key`:

```
select cbi_key
from mytable
group by cbi_key
having count(distinct aaa_key) > 1
```